# regex character appears exactly x times

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I'm working in bash and I have a large file in which I want to remove all the lines that do not match a certain regex, probably using `$ grep -e "<regex>" <file> > output.txt`

What I want to keep is any line that contain exactly *x* times a specified character, for example in the binary sequence

> 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101, 0111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111

I would like to keep only those who have 2 *1*, leaving me with

> 0011, 0101, 0110, 1001, 1010, 1100

I would then use a bash variable to vary the amount I need (always exactly half of the length, working with strings of the same length)
I'm litterally looking for lines that are half *0* and half *1*

I have this right now. It's not using regex. It works, but is very slow:

(`$1` is the length of every string, `$d` is just a directory)

```
sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1 /g' < $d/input.txt > $d/spaces.txt
awk '{c=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){c+=$i};print c}' $d/spaces.txt > $d/sums.txt
grep -n "$(($1/2))" $d/sums.txt | cut -f1 -d: > $d/linenums.txt
for i in $(cat $d/linenums.txt)
do
    sed "${i}q;d" $d/input.txt 
done > $d/valids.txt
```

In case you wonder this puts spaces in between every digit turning `1010` into `1 0 1 0`, then it adds the values together, saves the results in sums.txt, grep for length/2 and save only the line numbers in linenums.txt, then it reads linenums.txt and outputs the corresponding line from input.txt to output.txt

I need something quicker, the for loop is what's taking way too long

Thanks for your time and for sharing your knowledge with me.

Comment: How about KISS? `grep -E '0011|0101|0110|1001|1010|1100'`

Answer (score 2):

you can definitely make this faster.

here is a `grep` regex example to match any lines with exactly two occurrences of `1`:

```
grep '^\([^1]*1[^1]*\)\{2\}$' input.txt
```

you can generalize this to match exactly `n` occurrences of `c`:

```
grep "^\([^$c]*$c[^$c]*\)\{$n\}\$" input.txt
```

you also mentioned wanting to match lines that are half `0`s, half `1`s. since you stipulated that all the lines are of the same length, you can consider only the first line, and use `awk` (or `wc`) to get line length and choose `n`:

```
n=`head -n1 input.txt | awk '{printf "%d\n",length($0)/2}'`
c=1
grep "^\([^$c]*$c[^$c]*\)\{$n\}\$" input.txt
```

Comment: OK, thanks a lot, it works and it does so much faster than mine. Working with small sample files made me think it worked fine, but when working with  65536 (2^16) entries it showed how slow the thing was, I solved the first part on my own, but this one had me thinking for a while!